# C++ Skipping first default parameter in call

Tags: c++

Does anyone know why the first default parameter is not being set to default. When I run this the `char` 'P' is being set to the `int` `max_width` and in term `cout` is printing some large number for `max_width`. The character in the `printe` function reverts to the default. I am confused, I thought functions could tell which type is being used and use that for the parameter in question. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
void printe(int max_width = 1, char character = '*');

int main()
{
    char character = 'P';
    printe(character);
    return 0;
}

void printe(int max_width, char character)
{
    cout << max_width << " " << character << endl;
}
```

Comment: You are passing `'P'` , so the default is not used. That's what "default" means, it's a value that is used if you did not supply one

Comment: This is not allowed in C++. C++ only allow default parameter from right to left.

Comment: P is a char not an int so shouldnt it be used as the char argument. I am trying to supply one argument just for the second char parameter

Comment: No, your list of arguments has to be in the same order as the parameter list in the function prototype. Any default values can only come from after that.

Comment: you should consider reordering your function parameters.

Comment: "P is a char not an int". Learn about *integral promotion*.

Comment: clarifying what @nm said: `character` is a `char`, however `char` can be converted to `int` implicitly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does not skip the parameters by checking the type of the argument. However, it will try to cast the supplied arguments to match the parameters of the method signature.

What happens here is this: When you pass a `char` variable to the `printe` function, it will be implicitly cast to an `int`. So your code effectively is,

```
printe((int)character);
```

`max_width` parameter <strike>will take the value 80, which is the ASCII value of 'P'</strike>. [Edit: actually `char` to `int` cast (numeric coversion) is [a bit complex than that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast), which is why the OP gets a large number for `max_width`.]

Default parameters are designed so that methods can have *optional* parameters. You may consider reordering your parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest and easiest fix would be to switch the order of the parameters in your function:

```
void printe(char character = '*', int max_width = 1);

int main()
   {
   char character = 'P';
   printe(character);
   return 0;
   }
void printe(char character, int max_width)
{  cout << max_width << " " << character << endl; }
```

You can't skip parameters as you were trying to do. If you want to pass a character, and have max_width set to default, this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You could provide an overload for `printe` with it accepting only one argument which is the character.

```
void printe(char character);
```

Note that I have left out the default value for `character`, as calling `printe()` without arguments would result in ambiguity.

**UPDATE:** I felt the need to provide the `printe()` overload's implementation. It's really simple. You just have to delegate/call the original `printe()` filling in the rest of the parameters with your supposed default values:

```
void printe(char character) {
    printe(1, character);
}
```

Still I think @MGaz's answer is more sensible. It is quite rare for me to see print functions having parameters other than what is to be printed as the first parameters. Compare

```
printe('x', 42);   // What @MGaz is proposing
```

with

```
printe(42, 'x');   // Yours
```

Surely most programmers would prefer having (and calling) the former.

Ah well, I really do not know what `printe` does, so I leave it up to you to provide what you think is best for your stuff.

Comment: Although it's not a print function, `std::string(42, 'x')` uses OP's order (as does vector etc.)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Ah yes. I just saw `printe`'s definition (I seem to have ignored that part while reading through the question). I was quite sure that `max_width` is like the CSS max-width where stuff expands...

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not support function calls like

```
printe(, character);
```

You have to change the order of the parameters. You cannot pass the second parameter without the first.